What would be the distribution of $(S_1+S_2)^{-1}S_1$, where $S_1$ and $S_2$ follows Wishart distribution?
Given $S_1\sim W_p(n_1, \Sigma), S_2\sim W_p(n_2, \Sigma)$ follow Wishart distribution, it is well known that
$$U = (S)^{-1/2}S_1(S^{-1/2})^T,$$
$$\text{where }S = S_1 + S_2\text{ and }(S)^{1/2}\text{ is the unique lower triangular matrix with }(S)^{1/2}[(S)^{1/2}]^T = S$$
follows a matrix-variate beta distribution with $B_p(n_1/2, n_2/2)$.
The above results and the moments of the each element of $U$ can be found in Mitra (1970) and Konno (1988).
I'm wondering the distributional properties of the inverse of the sum of two Wishart-distributed matrices multiplied by one of the matrice, which is $$V = (S)^{-1}S_1.$$
Since the form is very similar to $U$, I tried to use the analogous concept of matrix-variate beta distribution, but still kind of struggling to proceed or find any known paper about the distribution or moments of the random variable $V$.
